# Redis hash values can not be shown in chronological order

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, socket.io

I have a real-time chat application using socket.io, node.js, and redis.

I need to add delete function so that users can delete their comments if they want to. 
To make this work, I need to assign a unique id to each comment, so only the selected comment will be deleted.

I can not use redis's `list` because there is no room for unique id. `List` can only take `key` and `value`. That's it.

So, I found `hash` that takes `key`, `field(unique id)`, and `value`. At first, this looked working great on my chat application and I was able to show comments using `hvals`, but soon I realized that those comments were shown in a random order. This order problem wasn't there when I was using `list`.

I did research on whether I could show comments in chronological order using `hash`, but it seems like it's impossible to do so.

What is the best way to handle this situation?
Should I abandon my redis code and go for mongodb or any other database for this purpose?
If I can keep using redis for this purpose, could you tell me how I can get around this problem using redis? I prefer to keep using redis if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a sorted set, which is a set where each value has a score, and you can sort by scores. the scores should be time stamps, and the values the messages and their ids.

Comment: That absolutely makes sense. Thank you for your answer.